# Extract multiple line string from HTML file using specific tags

Tags: html

I need to extract the string which are starting with the tag `<span class="style530">` and ending with `</span>` tag.

I used sed command but didn't get desired result. Below is sample code:

```
<strong>
-
<span class="style530">
AA - 
This
is my
First
Heading</span></strong><br>
<span class="style530">
<strong>
*Some
text,*
<strong>
*text*</strong>, 
*text*
<strong>
*text*</strong>: 
<br>
<span class="style530">
<strong>
- This 
is my
Second Heading</strong></span><br>
<span class="style530">
<strong>
*Some
text,*
<strong>
*text*</strong>, 
*Here
is some
text.*
<strong>*text*</strong>: 
*Here is 
some
text*.<br>
<br>
<strong>
-
<span class="style530">
- This is
my Third
Heading</span></strong><br>
```

Output should be like:

```
 AA - This is my First Heading
 - This is my Second Heading
 - This is my Third Heading
```

Thanks!

Comment: The standard warning here is [you cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1151724), so if this is for full pages whose content may vary, you should use an HTML parser.  However, if it is just a short, predictable segment like this you may be able to do something.

Comment: Can you provide more concise input and show what have you done?

Comment: Also your example and requirement doesn't match your output, there is more text under `<span class="style530">` tags than just the headings you note and your html is invalid or incomplete

Comment: Thanks for answer! 
@mtm the code is like that only, only few <span class="style530"> tags is closing with </span> and i need to extract only those strings which are closing with tag </span>

Answer (score 2):

[Regex isn't really capable of parsing html completely.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1318694)

There is a command line tool called [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) that lets you use XPath or CSS selectors to pull out the bits you want.

Something like this would meet your stated requirement:

```
./xidel test.html --extract '//span[@class="style530"]' --output-format bash
```

But note that this returns more than your required output as you have one unclosed `<span class="style530">`

Answer (score 1):

Use HTMLParser for such actions:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# vim: set fileencoding=utf8 :
# (c) fazie

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import re
import sys

class MyParser(HTMLParser):
    inside_span = False

    def __init__(self,file):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        f = open(file)
        self.feed(f.read())

    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        if tag == 'span':
            for name,value in attrs:
                if name=='class' and value=='style530':
                    self.inside_span=True

    def handle_data(self,data):
        data = data.strip(' \t\r\n')
        if data != "":
            if self.inside_span:
                data = re.sub('\n',' ',data)
                data = re.sub('\s\s+',' ',data)
                print data

    def handle_endtag(self,tag):
        if tag == 'span':
            self.inside_span=False

MyParser(sys.argv[1])
```

Run it:

```
python myparser.py inputfile.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below.

```
awk -vRS='<' '
  inside || /^span[^>]*class="style530"/ {
    inside = 1
    if (/^span/)
      n++
    else if (/^\/span>/ && !--n) {
      $0="/span>\n"
      inside=0
    }
    printf "<%s", $0
  }' file.html | sed '/^</ d' | grep -v ">$"
```

However, it is not advisable to extract using HTML headers. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for why you should not parse HTML pages. I would suggest you to use `curl` and `w3m` to remove the HTML headers after which the parsing will become little simpler.

Comment: Thanks!
I'm getting all strings which are not required...
as i need only that string which are closing with the tag </span>

Answer (score 0):

For simple extractions from xml/html texts
I like to use xidel with **CSS selectors**.

In this example, to select all `span` elements with attribute `class` containing the word `style530`, we can use

```
xidel --css span.style530 --xml
```

`xidel` has many options. The input provided by question is a bit noisy. In less noisy situations, with `--xml` we may get something like

```
<xml>
  <span class="style530">case 1 </span>
  <span class="menu style530 otherclass">case 2 </span>
  ...
</xml>
```